# OCaml expected to have type unit

Tags: ocaml

When trying to run the following function in `OCaml`:

```
let rec func1 o_list =
    match o_list with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> let (nt,inner_list) = h in
      if check_if_clear inner_list then
        [nt,inner_list]::clear_rules
      func1 t
;;
```

the program outputs an error

> Characters 139-141:
>       [nt,inner_list]::clear_rules
>
> Error: This variant expression is expected to have type unit
>   The constructor :: does not belong to type unit

Also you can assume that the function `check_if_clear` always returns `true` for now.
`o_list` is a list of pair and pair itself contains an element and a list.
So it is something like this `[ 'x , ['a,'b,'c]]` and `clear_rules` is just an empty list at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem that I was facing in another way, instead of trying to use some external list, I made my function to return the desired list. Here is the code

```
let rec func1 o_list clear_list =
match o_list with

| [] -> clear_list
| h::t -> let (nt,inner_list) = h in
if check_if_clear inner_list then
func1 t ([nt,inner_list]::clear_list)
else
func1 t clear_list
;;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your original example seems to have a missing semicolon after `clear_rules`. Once that is inserted and with stubs for the additional functionality, the error message is reproducible. It has the following reason:

The `then` branch of the if-expression

```
if check_if_clear inner_list then
    [nt,inner_list]::clear_rules
```

returns a value of type `('nt_type, 'inner_list_type) list list`; this is because `[nt, inner_list]` constructs a single item list of the pair `(nt, inner_list)` and then the cons operator `::` makes it the head of a list. So, the `then` branch returns a non-unit type.

Conversely, the `else` branch (by virtue of not existing) has type unit (i.e. no actual value). But in OCaml, the types for the `then` and `else` branch of an expression must match (i.e. be of the same type or subtypes of a common supertype); an if expression without an `else` branch therefore always has type unit, and so does the `then` branch of such an expression. Because it doesn't in your case, the compiler tells you that (in a roundabout way), by noting that the cons operator `::` has a different type (it creates a list and returns it) than the unit type it had inferred.

I suspect from your comments that your intention was not to create a list, but to perform some action with a side effect. For this, you'll probably need to write that action differently.